# Flutter / Android: how display "virtual" drive in file explorer for cloud storage applications

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, drive, virtual-drive

I want to create a flutter application for a cloud storage application I am working on. I want this application to be able to "mount" a drive in the system file explorer that will then be linked to my cloud storage application (There are certain apps that can do this, NextCloud, IServ, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q1gS.png)). Is there an android reference page to such an API / or even an API wrapper for flutter?

I have tried google-ing, but have not found an answer on how to do this. I have also tried inspecting NextCloud's source code but didn't arrive at a solution neither.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used NextCloud.
But after reading your question and looking at the official documentation, there are client APIs available for NextCloud, and they are WebDAV based.

I don't know if you've tried it, but there's a package that allows you to use webdav in flutter. You can use it to get a list of files in NextCloud, and use the API to access specific files.

NextCloud API : https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/19/developer_manual/client_apis/WebDAV/basic.html#webdav-basics

webdav_client : https://pub.dev/packages/webdav_client

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Does android automatically append my WebDAV drive to the system file explorer? I have known about WebDAV beforehand, but this question is more about how to get such a drive registered to the system file explorers.